# Tracking a single domain but with multiple parameters in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have Google Analytics setup on our page which has the base url of www.mydomain.com/index.html.

That page can optionally have added parameters to it which only load specific elements, We have generated multiple custom urls.

e.g.

```
www.mydomain.com/index.html?Theme=Toilets&Tools=Yes
www.mydomain.com/index.html?Theme=Cars&Tools=No
www.mydomain.com/index.html?Theme=Housing&Tools=Yes
```

What I would like to do is to track each of these customs urls (also including the url that doesnt include the optional arguments) . What is the best way of doing this using Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is to track each of these customs urls

This already works by default in Google Analytics, you have no extra setup to perform.

#### how to use the built-in feature

Have a look at the report `Behavior > Site content > Pages`.

In there, you will see the number of visits for `/index.html`, as well as `/index.html?Theme=Housing&Tools=Yes` and all the other variants.

Using **filters** in that report, you can explore the data and see the measures for any specific theme and tools you are interested in (have a look at [advanced filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en)).

If you find yourself often using the same filter, you can save the filter with the [report shortcut feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2676996?hl=en).

#### how to dig deeper.

The filters should really be sufficient.

In case you want even more flexibility, you can use **[custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)**. This will allow you to track `themes` and `tools` parameters on their own. When your page loads, you can send the corresponding them and tools dimensions value to Google Analytics. I do not think that this extra development effort is worthy, given that the filters already should do the job.

Comment: i have had a look at Behavior > Site content > Pages. But it does not list the custom urls. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: 1. Go to the admin page for the property, then in the "View settings". Is "Exclude URL Query Parameters" empty?

Comment: 2. Are the url parameters sent from the server side, or is it a javascript that sets them after the page load?

Comment: "Exclude URL Query Parameters" is empty. The javascript creates the page client site depending on the parameters in the url.

Comment: You're telling that the pages load with the url parameters, right? What is the value that you see in "Page" inside "Behavior > Site content > Pages"?

Comment: Correct, the main page is http://www.mapping.cityoflondon.gov.uk/geocortex/mapping/?viewer=compass , other urls that are used include http://www.mapping.cityoflondon.gov.uk/geocortex/mapping/?viewer=compass&runworkflowbyid=Switch_layer_themes&LayerTheme=Show%20the%20Cycle%20Stands%20layers. The key thing that i want "tracked" is the following part "LayerTheme=Show the Cycle Stands layers" . Under "Behavior > Site content > Pages" I can see "/", "/?from=http://share-buttons.xyz/", /?from=http://www.traffic2cash.xyz/ and /?from=http://www.traffic-cash.xyz/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102019/discussion-between-mef-and-mapman).